# Session null in application after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application with two pages. One page is called `receiveRequest.aspx`. It receives requests  from other applications, keeps a value in session and redirects to `manage.aspx` page. But when I check the `manage.aspx` page for the session variable, it shows null.

Here is a portion of code from receiveRequest.aspx

```
 Session["ToDoListSession"] = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString();

 Response.Redirect(destPage, true);
```

Does any one have any clue why it's null ???

Comment: in destPage contains Session["ToDoListSession"] is null?

Comment: just a guess, try ending the request `Response.Redirect(destPage, false);` see what happens